# Flutter TapGestureRecognizer in text span not detect small words with different styles-- if it one or two characters

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, gesture, flutter-test

i have a word like ABCDE each char in text span with different style  recognizer not detect correctly 
EX:

```
recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTap = () => print('${char.key} onTap'),
```

some of them not print accurate 
but when all spans takes same style it works fine 
Flutter Version 
Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720], locale
en-US)

Comment: and your question is ...?

Comment: You tried to put the question the title, please edit it and add the question!

Comment: question edited

Comment: it works just fine: `Text.rich(TextSpan(
  children: ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'].map((l) => TextSpan(
    text: l,
    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
      ..onTap = () => print('$l tapped')
  )).toList(),
)),
`

Comment: with different styles not same style 
make 5 styles and test

Comment: so would you post your code? what styles did you use?

Comment: Map<String, Color> chars = {
    "A": Colors.red,
    "B": Colors.blue,
    "V": Colors.purple,
    "W w": Colors.black,
    "G": Colors.green,
  };

Comment: for (MapEntry<String, Color> char in chars.entries)
              TextSpan(
                text: char.key,
                style: TextStyle(color: char.value),
                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTap = () => print('${char.key} onTap'),
              )

Comment: `Text.rich(TextSpan(
  children: [for (var l in 'hello world'.split(''))
    TextSpan(
      text: l,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 5.0 + 4 * (l.codeUnitAt(0) - 'a'.codeUnitAt(0)),
        color: (l.codeUnitAt(0) - 'a'.codeUnitAt(0)).isOdd? Colors.red : Colors.orange,
      ),
      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
        ..onTap = () => print('$l tapped')
    )
  ]
)),`

Comment: h tapped is result of all chars 
can you told me if it works for you

Comment: if works fine 
pls provide me with your flutter version and channel

Comment: how it works for you ?
issue here is opened
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54690

Comment: Flutter 1.14.7-pre.83 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e10df3c1a6 (3 months ago) • 2020-02-01 11:23:01 +0800
Engine • revision e625e174c5
Tools • Dart 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.6.0 5ae5aff640)

Comment: it works on master not stable :)